How to get list of topics I have subscribed to in Firebase cloud messaging using http v1
I am a flutter developer. In my app I have used firebase cloud messaging service where I subscribe to various topics to which I get notifications on. Problem is I want to unsubscribe from several topics. In legacy method there was an API available to get list of topics I have subscribed based on token of the device. Is there any method to get the same using http v1?
Previously on legacy method I used this method to get list of topics and unsubscribe to them
FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topic)
String token = "";
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) {
  token = value!;
});
var options = BaseOptions(headers: {
  'Authorization':
      'key = Server Key'
});
var dio = Dio(options);
var response = await dio.get(
    'https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/' + token,
    queryParameters: {'details': true});
Map<String, dynamic> subscribedTopics = response.data['rel']['topics'];
for (var entry in subscribedTopics.entries) {
  await Future.delayed(
      Duration(milliseconds: 100)); // throttle due to 3000 QPS limit
  unawaited(FirebaseMessaging.instance
      .unsubscribeFromTopic(entry.key)); // import pedantic for unawaited
  debugPrint('Unsubscribed from: ' + entry.key);

